TypeError: DynamicFrameWriter.from_jdbc_conf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'catalog_connection'
I got a issue that , while running the update query in my aws glue job....I got to know that it is not possible currently to do the update in DB directly using AWS GLUE for both SQL and Mongo.
But then i searched a lot for doing this then I got to know about dynamic frame that we can read and write using that and will update. It is just the testing or POC for how to do that.
Now the issue is while doing
`glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
    frame=updated_dynamic_frame,
    connection_options={
        "url": jdbc_url,
        "dbtable": db_table,
        "user": jdbc_user,
        "password": jdbc_password,
        "driver": jdbc_driver,
        "mode": "update"  
    }
) `

I got the error :- {TypeError: DynamicFrameWriter.from_jdbc_conf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'catalog_connection'}
Also I want to know how to create "catalog_connection".
So can anybody help me with the error or provide me the better approach for doing this.
Now the issue is while doing

# save data in Redshift
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
    frame=dynamic_frame_iteration,
    catalog_connection="your_catalog_connection",
    connection_options={
        "database"   : "your_database",
        "dbtable"    : "public.your_temp_table",
        "preactions" : "...",
        "postactions": "BEGIN; .... END;"
    },
    redshift_tmp_dir="s3://your_s3_bucket/temporary/",
    transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame_iteration"
)

Regarding your_catalog_connection -> go to connection tab in the AWS glue service page, create a new JDBC connection using your credentials and replace your_catalog_connection with the name of your connection entry
